# grep command is not giving intended result

Tags: file, grep

I have set of words in text file and i want to search for these words in another set of files and write the results into an output file

Eg.
Input file contains data as below

```
KFIS000025-02555593
KFIS000025-02556443
KFIS000025-02555082
```

The files in which I need this to be searched is as below

```
PFZ_EDI850_JKC_MLC_ORDER_20170413155724.TXT
PFZ_EDI850_JKC_MLC_ORDER_20170414090413.TXT
PFZ_EDI850_JKC_MLC_ORDER_20170414162518.TXT
```

I am using the below grep command but it is giving me 0 results, However, when I check few manually the input data is present in this files.

```
grep –wFf val.txt -o *JKC* > results.txt
```

Can you tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: JFK is meant to be the files to search in?  Or you really meant  `*JFK*`

Comment: the file names contain JKC, I meant * JKC *

Comment: show the fragment of a file to be searched

Comment: the file tobe searched has the content shown in the begining
KFIS000025-02555593
KFIS000025-02556443
KFIS000025-02555082

and the above needs to be searched in file which has below data


ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*JKC_PFZ_MLC_SAP*ZZ*PFIZERINTUSPG  *170414*1624*U*00401*000002290*1*P*^~
GS*PO*JKC_PFZ_MLC_SAP*PFIZERINTUSPG*20170414*162433*2288*X*004030~
ST*850*4226965~
BEG*00*SP*KFIS000025-02586904*a04A000000ueSeVIAU*20170413~
PER*BD*ROBERT PICCIANO*TE*9786543210~
N1*ST*ROBERT PICCIANO MD~
N3*36 PACIFIC STREET~
N4*NEWARK*NJ*07105~
REF*OB*25MA05550400~

Comment: probably because of the `-o` typo? what is that option doing here?